# weight=1 and android:layout_width="0dp" makes my view disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I want to create a layout when I have an image, text aligned to the left of the layout.
and a chip aligned to the left.

[image]

I have tried this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/my_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/my_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/my_padding2"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/my_padding2"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/Icon"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/icon_margin"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      android:contentDescription="@null"
      android:importantForAccessibility="no"
      tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/Text"
      style="@style/ActionItemStyle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_icon_and_text"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_icon_and_text"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
      android:maxLines="3"
      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
  <com.my.Chip
      android:id="@+id/highlight_chip"
      style="@style/Widget.Chip.Suggestive"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_highlight_chip_and_text"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_highlight_chip_and_text"
      android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
      android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

meaning I have Chip with weight and layout_gravity, but the chip is not seen.

[image]

how can i fix this?

The strange thing is that I have tried

```
<com.my.Chip
      android:id="@+id/highlight_chip"
      style="@style/Widget.GoogleMaterial.Chip.Suggestive"
      android:layout_width="10dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_highlight_chip_and_text"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_highlight_chip_and_text"
      android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
      android:visibility="visible" />
```

without weight, and the chip still doesn't show

Comment: Why do you stick to to linear layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set `layout_weight` in your `com.my.Chip`

Try to set `android:layout_weight="1"` on your `TextView` instead of in your `com.my.Chip`

and also change `android:layout_width="0dp"` in your `TextView`

You will get output something like this

[image]

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/my_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/my_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/my_padding2"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/my_padding2"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/Icon"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/icon_margin"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      android:contentDescription="@null"
      android:importantForAccessibility="no"
      tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/Text"
      style="@style/ActionItemStyle"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_icon_and_text"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_icon_and_text"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
      android:maxLines="3"
      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
  <com.my.Chip
      android:id="@+id/highlight_chip"
      style="@style/Widget.Chip.Suggestive"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_highlight_chip_and_text"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_highlight_chip_and_text"
      android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
      android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: will try, but why does that matter where i put the weight?

Comment: @EladBenda if you want to set weight in your `com.my.Chip` then just change `width` of your `textView` to **`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`** it will work

Comment: @EladBenda [why does that matter where i put the weight?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3995825/7666442)

Comment: @NileshRathod, It matters where you put the weight. The parent has a defined `width` which we want to divide among the `child views`. So, the child view with highest priority gets `weight=1`, and the remaining views will either get `wrap_content` or `some dp value`. This is important because when android lays out the views, it assigns the values to the ones which don't have `weight` associated first, and whatever is remaining is assigned to the view with the `weight`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, while you provide "weight" attribute just to the textview, it will not render the expected output. You need to use "weight_sum" attribute to create an opening for all the three views which you have used inside the view group i.e. imageview, textview and the chip.
so the solution will look like this ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.6"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Demo Text" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

</LinearLayout>
```